# Read excel data from attachment and display in SharePoint and allowed to edit

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, excel

User would like to upload a excel file into SharePoint and he expect system to read his file and display out the data that he have uploaded in SharePoint. Besides, from SharePoint, he requested to allow other user to enter new data on top of his data but not allowed other people to modify his uploaded data.

For example, alpha, A, beta and B are uploaded data which not allowed to modify but user can add in new row or enter data in column C.

[image]

Is there any better way to do this? Should I display it in grid?

Appreciate if someone can provide some sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about not writing any custom functionality at all?

Instead use a SharePoint list where you add the needed columns!

The users could then use [Datasheet view](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/sharepoint-lists-i-an-introduction-RZ101820091.aspx?section=4) to edit and add items.

In `List Settings - Advanced - Item level Permissions` you could cofigure so users are only allowed to modify their own items, see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61273/2010-allow-users-to-add-to-a-list-and-edit-or-delete-only-their-own-posts)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but by using Datasheet view, user are able to modify the whole list data but my requirement is user want to do multiple different excel record in different of form/list item. Impossible 1 excel for 1 list... Please advise